# Application Insights SDK - Collect only specific dependencies?

Tags: .net-core, azure-application-insights

This [document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#setup-automatic-dependency-tracking-in-console-apps) shows how to track dependencies on my console app. But I would like to collect only Http dependencies by default. I would like to disable the collection of SQL Server dependencies and others. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to filter out (and drop) what you need using [Telemetry Processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling).

Something like this:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

public class DependencyFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    // next will point to the next TelemetryProcessor in the chain.
    public DependencyFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        // To filter out an item, return without calling the next processor.
        if (!OKtoSend(item)) { return; }

        this.Next.Process(item);
    }

    // Example: replace with your own criteria.
    private bool OKtoSend (ITelemetry item)
    {
        var dependency = item as DependencyTelemetry;
        if (dependency == null) return true;

        return dependency.Type.Contains("HTTP");
    }
}
```